# Asynchronous calls returning error

Tags: apex, webservices, docusign

While performing callouts over Docusign API ([here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures)) from an Apex class it works fine. And whenever I try to introduce any Asynchronous callouts (future / batch) it generates an error.

I'm wondering why this is happening as there is only the difference of mechanism here. So, it works perfectly in a normal Apex call.

My Bussiness process to call the api has changed: I want to make callouts on record Update / Create / Delete event. So, Trigger is the only way I need to use. And to make callouts from a Trigger require an Asynchronous call (via future annotated with callouts=true). But this doesn't work for me currently.

So, I end up making this Business Process with 2 solutions (neither of them is working):

```
1). Apex Trigger -> Apex Class containing a future method annotated callouts=true.
2). Apex Trigger -> Apex Batch with Database.AllowsCallouts implementation
```

Following is the error I'm getting using Asynchronous call:

```
Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: An Error Occurred during anchor tag processing. Invalid document faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx"
```

I’m pretty sure that this is Salesforce related error but I can’t fathom out why.

Answer (score 1):

I looked on Google, it appears someone else had the same issue over the DocuSign boards.

http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-Ruby-Salesforce-and-Other-READ-ONLY/The-problem-with-using-DocuSign-API-from-apex-class/td-p/19245

Looks like you need to use a different endpoint:

https://docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

Comment: Thanks for this but this doesn't solve my problem yet!

Comment: Do you get the same error even after changing the endpoint from dsapi.asmx to api.asmx?

Comment: Yes, its the same error I'm still getting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same DocuSign exception message. The root cause in my case was the document blob, or more specifically the underlying code used to generate the blob. I use a visualforce page to render the pdf and the page's controller wasn't assigning a variable that is used in the page. Seeing the exception message in the logs helped pinpoint the cause.

```
System.debug('Rendering the doc');
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/caseDoc');
pageRef.getParameters().put('id',cId);
// test methods do not support getContent(). Added try catch for purposes of testing.
try {
    pdfBlob = pageRef.getContent();
} catch (VisualforceException e){
    pdfBlob = Blob.valueof('Case Doc');
    system.debug('***doc exception');
}
```